# Virtuabox not working with Genymotion? Can't open Virtualbox at all

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion

I have the latest versions of Genymotion (2.8.0) and Virtualbox (5.0.4). If I try to run any emulator through Genymotion, I get an error message:

"Unable to start the virtual device.

VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device.

To find out the cause of the problem, start the virtual device from VirtualBox."

If I try to start Virtualbox it doesn't run at all. Absolutely nothing shows up, not even in task manager. I read on VirtualBox forum it might have something to do with Windows 10, but no one seems to have a exact fix.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem after updating to Win10 RS, was solved by updating VirtualBox to the latest version. (I have Genymotion 2.8.0 and VirtualBox 5.1.4)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on MS Win 10, which you might be, its:

In my case (Windows 10 with VirtualBox 5.0.10 and Genymotion 2.6.0) i had to:

Go to network connections (run control netconnections from cmd)
Right click and properties on VirtualBox Host-Only Network
Enable VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver

That everything works fine

Comment: Didn't work. I have two networks, both already had NDIS6 Bridged Networking enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Am using windows 8 and this solved my problem. Redownload genymotion with virtual box interface. At genymotion website there are two options one with virtual box interface and one without. Download and install the one with vb interface,

Then after successifull installation there are those prompts you get when starting a device you must click okay on them then am sure it will work